# Trouble joining a list of string

Tags: python, unicode

In an application I get a dictionary from another process. This dictionary has some non-ascii characters like `Ä`.

I want to generate a json string out of this dictionary, but all I get is

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)`

So I started a `pudb` session and stepped into the code until I've found the line where the exception is thrown.

On my python version (2.7.9, anaconda build) the `JSONEncoder` class, `encode` function.

```
def encode(self, o):
    ...
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
        chunks = list(chunks)
    return ''.join(chunks)
```

The `''.join(chunks)`is what generate this problem. In the `pudb` console I've managed to find the index of the in `chunks` that yields the error, #355

```
In [51]: chunks[355]
Out[51]: '"Datum Erfassung / \xc3\x84nderung"'
```

The Text is `"Datum Erfassung / Änderung"`. To me this seems valid utf-8 code, [this documentation](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c4/index.htm) says that for U+00E4 the utf-8 hex is `0xC3 0x84`. But if I do

```
In [53]: u'Ä'
Out[53]: u'\xc4'
```

Why do I get `0xC4` here?

In another thread someone suggested that the string should be converted with `str` to basically remove the encoding. So I tried

```
In [54]: ''.join([str(x) for x in chunks])
```

and this time it worked, no errors. But if I do:

```
for ch in chunks:
    if str(ch) != ch:
        print "'%s' differs" % str(ch)
```

the output remains empty. And don't get why `''.join(chunk)` doesnt't work but `''.join([str(x) for x in chunks])` does.

What am I missing?

btw:  `chardet.detect(chunks[355])` outputs `{'confidence': 0.73, 'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'language': ''}`. Is that really so?

Comment: You should show exactly how you try to build the JSON string. My 2.7.12 doc says that JSONEncoder should use utf8 by default, to the error referencing *ascii* codec is weird...

Comment: with `json.dumps(response, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)`. The error happens when `ensure_ascii` is set to `False`, but if it is not passed, then there is also no error.

Comment: Do response contains only unicode strings, only UTF8 encoded byte strings, could contain a mix of both or could even contain byte strings in another encoding?